# Trouble with rigid type variables

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a parser for a simplistic DSL.

I'm running into trouble with the following function:

```
procP ::  ((a->Bool) -> [a] -> Bool) -> String -> Comperator -> ([String] -> Bool)
procP q v c =
  case c of
      NumE   -> q ((==) . unMay . readDouble $ v) . mapMaybe readDouble
      NumNE  -> q ((/=) . unMay . readDouble $ v) . mapMaybe readDouble
      NumLTE -> q ((<=) . unMay . readDouble $ v) . mapMaybe readDouble
      NumLT  -> q ((<)  . unMay . readDouble $ v) . mapMaybe readDouble
      NumGTE -> q ((>=) . unMay . readDouble $ v) . mapMaybe readDouble
      NumGT  -> q ((>)  . unMay . readDouble $ v) . mapMaybe readDouble
      Exists -> q notBlanks
      DatE   -> q ((==) . unMay . p_date $ v ) . mapMaybe p_date
      DatNE  -> q ((/=) . unMay . p_date $ v ) . mapMaybe p_date
      DatLTE -> q ((<=) . unMay . p_date $ v ) . mapMaybe p_date
      DatLT  -> q ((<)  . unMay . p_date $ v ) . mapMaybe p_date
      DatGTE -> q ((>=) . unMay . p_date $ v ) . mapMaybe p_date
      DatGT  -> q ((>)  . unMay . p_date $ v ) . mapMaybe p_date
      TxtE   -> q (==v)
      TxtME  -> (q (==v)) . map (rTrim)
      TxtNME -> (q (/=v)) . map (rTrim)
      TxtNE  -> q (/= v)
```

The breakdown here is as follows:

`q` is some function that works like `any` from prelude. There are a couple different variations, but the type signature should be more or less the same - given a predicate and a list, return a bool.

`v` is a string input for purposes of comparison, it helps construct the predicate.

`c` is a token type constructed by the parser that represents what type of comparison we should use in the predicate.

`unMay` is a stupid hack function to "unwrap" a `Just` value or error on `Nothing`.

`readDouble` and `p_date` are functions that take a `String` and return either a `Maybe Day` or `Maybe Double`, respectively.

The design intent here is that the we're using the `Comparator` token to tell us what type to change the input `String`s to internally, so that I can choose whether to compare against a value as a `String`, `Day`, or `Double`, respectively.

Sort of like a super basic version of what Perl does with `==` vs `eq`, but with less coercion and more nasty error messages.

The problem I'm having is that this doesn't type check, because the predicate getting passed to `q` ends up presenting as type `Double->Bool` instead of `a->Bool`, and so I get an error about how `a` is a rigid type variable.

The error more or less makes sense to me, but I'm having a lot of trouble thinking of a way to get around the problem.

Does anyone have any advice on how to re-structure this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: GHC cannot deduce type. Rigid type variable bound by the type signature error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778098/haskell-ghc-cannot-deduce-type-rigid-type-variable-bound-by-the-type-signature)

Comment: Shouldn't v also be `rTrim`'d for `TxtME` and `TxtNME`?

Comment: @Gurkenglas - Nice catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on `Rank2Types` (e.g. by putting `{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}` at the top of your file) and write

```
--         vvvvvvvvv difference is here
procP ::  (forall a. (a->Bool) -> [a] -> Bool) -> String -> Comperator -> ([String] -> Bool)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly and was much less work than I'd feared.